# Android Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError en ArrayList metodo add en un while

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hola comunidad stackoverflow tengo el error de java.lang.OutOfMemoryError cuando le vas a dar add a un array list en un while. Cabe resaltar que las primeras 40 veces que funciona bien la 41ava vez funciona mal.

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 16409080 byte allocation with 4687544 free bytes and 4577KB until OOM, target footprint 100663296, growth limit 100663296
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3136)
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3106)
        at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:275)
        at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:249)
        at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:241)
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:467)
        at com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app.ui.packing.ProduccionPackingSemanaRendimientoActivity.onCreate(ProduccionPackingSemanaRendimientoActivity.java:235)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7822)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7811)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1328)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3452)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3620)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2183)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7604)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

El error ocurre en la linea: listaSemanaAnio.add(semanaPoner + "/" + anioDia);

El ArrayList listaSemanaAnio se crea afuera del onCreate: List listaSemanaAnio = new ArrayList<>();

El add ocurre en un while que esta en el onCreate

```
while(!(semanaDia == semanaComienzoTemporada -1) || !(anioDia == anioComienzoTemporada)) {
            if (semanaDia == 1) {
                if(semanaDia == primeraSemana && anioDia == primerAnio) {
                    listaSemanaAnio.add("01" + "/" + anioDia + " (*)");
                    //System.out.println(semanaDia + "/" + anioDia);
                    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                    calendar.set(anioDia, 0, 0);
                    int semanaSpinner = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
                    if (semanaSpinner == 1) {
                        calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
                        semanaSpinner = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
                    }
                    anioDia = anioDia - 1;
                    semanaDia = semanaSpinner;
                }else{
                    listaSemanaAnio.add("01" + "/" + anioDia);
                    //System.out.println(semanaDia + "/" + anioDia);
                    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                    calendar.set(anioDia, 0, 0);
                    int semanaSpinner = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
                    if (semanaSpinner == 1) {
                        calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
                        semanaSpinner = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
                    }
                    anioDia = anioDia - 1;
                    semanaDia = semanaSpinner;
                }
            } else {
                if(semanaDia == primeraSemana && anioDia == primerAnio) {
                    String semanaPoner = "";
                    if (semanaDia == 2) {
                        semanaPoner = "02";
                    } else if (semanaDia == 3) {
                        semanaPoner = "03";
                    } else if (semanaDia == 4) {
                        semanaPoner = "04";
                    } else if (semanaDia == 5) {
                        semanaPoner = "05";
                    } else if (semanaDia == 6) {
                        semanaPoner = "06";
                    } else if (semanaDia == 7) {
                        semanaPoner = "07";
                    } else if (semanaDia == 8) {
                        semanaPoner = "08";
                    } else if (semanaDia == 9) {
                        semanaPoner = "09";
                    } else {
                        semanaPoner = String.valueOf(semanaDia);
                    }

                    listaSemanaAnio.add(semanaPoner + "/" + anioDia + " (*)");
                    semanaDia = semanaDia - 1;
                }else{
                    String semanaPoner = "";
                    if (semanaDia == 2) {
                        semanaPoner = "02";
                    } else if (semanaDia == 3) {
                        semanaPoner = "03";
                    } else if (semanaDia == 4) {
                        semanaPoner = "04";
                    } else if (semanaDia == 5) {
                        semanaPoner = "05";
                    } else if (semanaDia == 6) {
                        semanaPoner = "06";
                    } else if (semanaDia == 7) {
                        semanaPoner = "07";
                    } else if (semanaDia == 8) {
                        semanaPoner = "08";
                    } else if (semanaDia == 9) {
                        semanaPoner = "09";
                    } else {
                        semanaPoner = String.valueOf(semanaDia);
                    }

                    listaSemanaAnio.add(semanaPoner + "/" + anioDia);
                    semanaDia = semanaDia - 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Ya probe con esta solucion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio poniendole android:hardwareAccelerated="false" y android:largeHeap="true" primero los dialog se ponen con bordes negros y sale esto hasta que da error

```
2020-12-29 10:22:43.034 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@dd21c12
2020-12-29 10:22:43.204 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app W/asa.packing3ap: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/View;->mAccessibilityDelegate:Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-12-29 10:22:46.143 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@470bd64
2020-12-29 10:22:46.177 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
2020-12-29 10:22:47.013 32626-32645/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 411948(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 41% free, 34MB/58MB, paused 95us total 140.423ms
2020-12-29 10:22:47.233 32626-32645/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 839179(23MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 50MB/58MB, paused 121us total 116.125ms
2020-12-29 10:22:47.583 32626-32645/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 737545(28MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 26% free, 65MB/89MB, paused 109us total 230.905ms
2020-12-29 10:22:47.755 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:47.835 32626-32645/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 1146488(31MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 27% free, 64MB/88MB, paused 101us total 127.458ms
2020-12-29 10:22:47.835 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on ClassLinker for 79.970ms
2020-12-29 10:22:47.835 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:47.979 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:48.046 32626-32645/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 524987(14MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 81MB/88MB, paused 158us total 129.541ms
2020-12-29 10:22:48.046 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on ClassLinker for 67.648ms
2020-12-29 10:22:48.046 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:48.127 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:48.453 32626-32645/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Clamp target GC heap from 96MB to 96MB
2020-12-29 10:22:48.453 32626-32645/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 607976(23MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 72MB/96MB, paused 46us total 371.974ms
2020-12-29 10:22:48.453 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on ClassLinker for 326.034ms
2020-12-29 10:22:48.453 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:48.585 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:48.681 32626-32645/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 627509(17MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 78MB/96MB, paused 108us total 100.968ms
2020-12-29 10:22:48.681 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on HeapTrim for 96.514ms
2020-12-29 10:22:48.681 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:48.779 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:49.222 32626-32645/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Clamp target GC heap from 106MB to 96MB
2020-12-29 10:22:49.222 32626-32645/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 475138(13MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 13% free, 82MB/96MB, paused 58us total 446.075ms
2020-12-29 10:22:49.222 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on HeapTrim for 442.561ms
2020-12-29 10:22:49.222 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:49.295 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:49.370 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on HeapTrim for 75.581ms
2020-12-29 10:22:49.370 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:49.422 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:49.854 32626-32645/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Clamp target GC heap from 112MB to 96MB
2020-12-29 10:22:49.854 32626-32645/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Background concurrent copying GC freed 263324(7488KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 88MB/96MB, paused 47us total 435.429ms
2020-12-29 10:22:49.855 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on HeapTrim for 432.676ms
2020-12-29 10:22:49.855 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:49.898 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:49.963 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on HeapTrim for 64.289ms
2020-12-29 10:22:49.963 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:49.987 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/chatty: uid=10461(com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app) identical 1 line
2020-12-29 10:22:49.987 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:50.234 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Clamp target GC heap from 115MB to 96MB
2020-12-29 10:22:50.234 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 127772(3645KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 91MB/96MB, paused 47us total 247.100ms
2020-12-29 10:22:50.234 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:50.245 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Alloc young concurrent copying GC freed 0(15KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 91MB/96MB, paused 53us total 10.683ms
2020-12-29 10:22:50.245 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:50.479 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Clamp target GC heap from 115MB to 96MB
2020-12-29 10:22:50.479 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 6(16KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 91MB/96MB, paused 48us total 233.364ms
2020-12-29 10:22:50.479 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 15MB allocation
2020-12-29 10:22:50.479 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-12-29 10:22:51.051 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Clamp target GC heap from 115MB to 96MB
2020-12-29 10:22:51.052 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app I/asa.packing3ap: Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 4748(192KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(32KB) LOS objects, 4% free, 91MB/96MB, paused 47us total 572.608ms
2020-12-29 10:22:51.059 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app W/asa.packing3ap: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 16409080 byte allocation with 4687544 free bytes and 4577KB until OOM, target footprint 100663296, growth limit 100663296" (VmSize 4736604 kB)
2020-12-29 10:22:51.059 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-12-29 10:22:51.110 32626-32626/com.sociedadagricoladrokasa.packing3app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Ayudeneme porfavor.

Saludos.

Luis Miguel Casas.

Comment: Has revisado cuantos elementos tratas de insertar en :  listaSemanaAnio.add(semanaPoner + "/" + anioDia); ?

Comment: revisa tu condicional, supongo que alguna de las dos siempre se sigue cumpliendo y se cicla tu sistema. Al menos viéndolo muy por encima, puede que ese or deba de ser un and y ahí radique el problema

Comment: @Jorgesys los elementos varian desde 1 hasta 53 o 54 elementos para el arrayList listaSemanaAnio

Comment: @L.Ronquillo no creo que el condicional este mal si funciona solo que a la 41ava vez que se ejecuta la aplicación se cae y sale ese error.

Comment: Según la excepción, se está excediendo la capacidad del ArrayList, por lo que obviamente se está terminando en un ciclo infinito tu algoritmo. Ese problema no debe resolverse de manera "forzada", agregando propiedades al manifest ni mucho menos. Dicha excepción es lanzada desde la clase ArrayList. Trata de cambiar la lógica o arreglar las condiciones de tu `while`.

Comment: Gracias Andrespengineer era que el while era infinito.